# ModuleNotFoundedError:No modul named flask

Tags: python, html, css, visual-studio-code

I am using Windows 10 Home. I have Python 3.9.1 and Visual studio code.I am studying to Flask in Visual Studio Code. I already installed Flask.But when I try to run this code in visual studio codes tereminal:

`python file.py #the file is the name of the my test page`

I take the no modul named flask.But when I try to run my codes its working.Or I try to again install flask
the output says I was already have flask.

Note:I am new about the programs.So I don't know what should I do?
Note2:I am trying to run Python codes with HTML and CSS.

Comment: So how do you "run your codes" in a way that they do work? This sounds like the terminal you're using isn't using the same Python interpreter or virtualenv that the working environment is.

Comment: I am using to Visual Studio Codes terminal @AKX

Comment: So are or are you not able to run the program? If you are, show the steps that do work, then show the steps that don't work (and which should). It's really hard to tell what's happening here.

Comment: Ok I am explaning.I following someone who teaches Flask.And I did what it say. After I run to py file and it was working.But after teacher say I should start the flask server with 'python file.py'.But when I run this codes I take an error. @AKX

Comment: @white -When you enter "pip show flask", does the terminal of VS Code output the information of the module "flask"?

Comment: Yes,it's working @JillCheng

Comment: @white  -In the currently open project, is there a python file named "flask.py" in the python file you created? Please try to reload VS Code.

Comment: No,There isn't here flask.py file.But there is flask.cpython-39.pyc python file.Am I doing wrong something? @JillCheng

Comment: @white -When you type "pip show flask", where is the module displayed on the terminal? Please try to reinstall the module "flask" in the current python environment.

Comment: When I wrote VS code terminal and I was press the enter ,I see the information about the flask under the "pip show flask"'s line.And I removed the VS code and after I again download the VS code.But I still take the same error.@JillCheng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using "flask" in VS Code, you could refer to the following:

1. Check whether the python used by the terminal is the same as the selected python: (`python --version` or `pip --version`)

   [image]
2. Installation. (`pip install flask`)
3. Check the module: (`pip show flask`)
4. Run:

   [image]

Reference: [Flask Tutorial in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask).

Comment: Thank you so much @JillCheng.Now I don't take it error.But If it possible,I have one more question.When I try to run my code its don't working.It goes to the next line without displaying any information.Do you know what should I do?

Comment: @white -What is the code snippet you are using? It is recommended that you create a new question and describe the problem in detail. And if my answer solves the problem in this thread, please [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to help others find this solution.

Comment: Again thank you very much @JillCheng.Your suggestions very helpful for me.